# How to group and count by specific criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with cars and garages. Each car is listed in only one garage, but a single garage can have a lot of cars. I want to know how many of each car type there is in a garage. Every car has it's own row in the database.

The table looks like this one.

```
+-------+--------+-----+
|carType| garage |id   |
+-------+--------+-----+
| 1     | 1      | 1   |
+-------+--------+-----+
| 1     | 1      | 2   |
+-------+--------+-----+
| 1     | 2      | 3   |
+-------+--------+-----+
| 2     | 2      | 4   |
+-------+--------+-----+
```

This is what I want to get.

```
+-------+------------+--------+
|carType| carCount   | garage |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 1     | 2          | 1      |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 1     | 1          | 2      |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 2     | 1          | 2      |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

The problem is that I have no idea how the query should look.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I know that I have to use group by and count, but if I group by type it ignores the garages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `GROUP BY` `carType` *and* `garage`:

```
SELECT carType, COUNT(*) AS carCount, garage
FROM cars
GROUP BY carType, garage
```

Output:

```
carType garage  carCount
1       1       2
1       2       1
2       2       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5E1RhqByK35A2UsW797T22/0)

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt at answering something on here, hope it does the trick!
As Gordon says Hint Group By, if below not right please shout out Gordon.

```
with t
as
(select * from(values(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,3),(2,2,4)) as t (carType,garage,id))

select carType, count(id) as carCount, garage
from t
group by carType, garage
```